# iOS BLE accessory would like to open App when the app is not being viewed. How to silent this alert?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an iOS app that connect to a BLE device. After I connect the app with the BLE device by `CBCentralManager.connect` then press the home button, if the BLE device sends data to my app at this time, iOS will make an alert saying "The <device name> accessory would like to open <App name>" with a "Close" and a "View" button. Since my BLE device is sending data continuously, this alert will keep poping up. Even worse when connected to multiple devices since different devices give this alert and the alert window keeps switching back and forth to a point that it is impossible to click the button on the alert window. Is there a way to silent this alert?

Comment: Enable "Uses Bluetooth Accessories" background mode or disconnect from the peripheral when entering the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either enable the “uses Bluetooth Accessories” background mode or disconnect from your peripherals when your app enters the background.